# Implementing an interface with different types

Tags: php, oop

I would like to have an interface that allows for a generic type

```
public function persist($object);
```

But my concrete implementations to have a type

```
public function persist(User $user);
```

From what I understand of PHP this is not possible. From an object oriented design point of view could someone explain to me why what I am doing is misguided and wrong.

Edit: I should clarify, I'm aware of type hinting and how it works my question is really trying to understand from an OO perspective where I am going wrong when I want my concrete implementation to take a different type to the interface.

Comment: okay. so you want type hinting in an interface method? if not could you elaborate more in the question with complete example?

Comment: From OOP point of view, I think you need adapter class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface's purpose is to be a contract between classes. An interface would be useless if multiple concrete classes implemented it, but all expected different inputs. By looking at the interface, you would not know what type of inputs that the implementing classes expect, thus making the interface basically useless. You could not interchange different concrete classes that all use the same interface, as they all expect different inputs (have different interfaces).

I could not replace classA with classB with the assurance that they would both work, since they both have the same interface. This would basically make interfaces useless for every OOP pattern known to man.

**EDIT EXAMPLE**

```
class CommandList {

    public function addCommand(Command $command) {
        $this->commands[] = $command;
    }

    public function runCommands() {
        foreach ($this->commands as $command) $command->run($this);
    }
}

interface Command {
    public function run(CommandList $commandList);
}

class Hop implements Command {
    public function run(CommandList $commandList) {
        // hop here
    }
}

class Skip implements Command {
    public function run(CommandList $commandList) {
        // skip here
    }
}
```

See how the interface acts as a contract? If you break that contact, then things that implement Command would not be interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to create an interface (or abstraction) for the  object being passed in.

Comment: Since an interface is a contract, all classes that implement that contract should be interchangeable when put into a method argument that accepts objects that follow that interface. I will edit to show an example.

Comment: Keep in mind you would probably not want to use CommandList as a type hint in the example above, otherwise the concrete class and it's extensions would be the only thing you could use with this. Instead there should be a CommandList interface that you could use for type hinting. This way you could make any class implement the CommandList interface, and then be sure that you can use them with Commands (classes that implement the Command interface).